# Checking if package is older than 24 hours with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to check if my last file is older than 24 hours or not. (project in django)
I have many zip packages in directory so I have to 'filter' the last one with this part of code: `ls -1 | sort -n | tail -n1`.

My code in .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$HOME/path_directory ls -1 | sort -n | tail -n1"
current=`date +%s`;
last_modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`;


if [ $(($current-$last_modified)) -gt 86400 ]; then
     echo "File is older that 24 hours" | mailx noreply@address -s "Older than 24 hours" me@mailmail.com
else
     echo "File is up to date.";
fi;
```

Here is an error, that I got:

```
stat: invalid option -- '1'
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
/path_directory/imported_file.sh: line 9: 1538734802-: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
```

If somebody made something similar, please some hint.

Comment: Why not with `find`?

Comment: Using back-ticks for command substitutions is deprecated in favor of `$(command)`.  The later form is more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise you to try this:

```
if test "`find file -mtime +1`"
```

but if you insist you can fix it by changing it to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$HOME/path_directory ls -1 | sort -n | tail -n1"
current=$(date +%s);
last_modified=$(stat -c "%Y" $file);

if [ $((current - last_modified)) -gt 86400 ]; then
     echo "File is older that 24 hours" | mailx noreply@address -s "Older than 24 hours" me@mailmail.com
else
     echo "File is up to date.";
fi;
```

Comment: Using back-ticks for command substitutions is deprecated in favor of `$(command)`.  The later form is more readable.

Comment: @ben Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the list of files in the directory that have been modified earlier than 1440 minutes (86400 seconds), you can use `find` for this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1440
```

It will thus select all files in *this* directory (no subdirectories), with a change time in minutes older than 1440.

The `+` in `+1440` is important, since otherwise you will obtain files that are *exactly* 1440 minutes unmodified.

You can also use `-mtime` to specify the number in days:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1
```

If you want all files (in this directory and subdirectories), you can remove the `-maxdepth 1`.

You can add `-type f` if you only want to include files, etc. For more flags, and (filtering) options, please read the [manpage of `find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: `cmin` and `ctime` represent the last inode change-time (permissions, name, etc.).  The OP wants the last modification timestamps --- `mmin` and `mtime`.

Comment: @JRFerguson: arrgh... Yes, `ctime` handles the meta-data. But `mtime` handles the content :)

Answer (score 2):

The file variable are not well formed I belive that you want something like:

```
file=`find $HOME/path_directory | sort -n | tail -n1`
```

or

```
file=$( find $HOME/path_directory | sort -n | tail -n1)
```

If you like the moderm way

Comment: Using back-ticks for command substitutions is deprecated in favor of `$(command)`.  The later form is more readable.